# what is difference between #import and inheritance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

in classa.h

```
#import "ClassB.h"
@inteface classa : ClassB
```

what is advantage of inheritance and what is advantage of import

please explain

in classa.m

```
    #import "ClassB.h"
```

access the member in class file.
same thing access the member in ClassB

what is different?

Comment: they are very basic concepts...

Comment: Same as the difference between apple and oranges. Both are different concepts..Plese modify your question or be specific.

Comment: Methinks you need to step back a bit and do a bit more research/learning on this.  This is a very broad question as is, an answer would basically be an introduction to object oriented programming...

Comment: see this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575160/objective-c-use-of-import-and-inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import gives files access to other class files, allowing the developer to create instances of those other classes, so that the files can interact.  Inheritance is a whole different concept.  Basically, if a class inherits form another class, it has all the objects and methods of that class, plus some.  For example, if you had a 'animal' class, it might contain such methods as eat, drink, and breathe.  Then, if you had a class called human, it could inherit from animal, meaning that it could still eat, drink, and breathe, but you would add in human-specific things, like name, social security number, etc.  Here is a good java explanation of inheritance, basically the same as in Objective-C:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: but we can import that animal class and can use these functions. then why inherit ?

Comment: If you just import the animal class into the human class, a human will not be an animal.  You will not be able to call the eat, drink, and breathe functions on a human.  You will only be able to create animals, and make them eat drink and breathe.  These animals will not be humans.